# Counting cases in divisibility test

Tags: probability, combinatorics, divisibility

> If S={1,2,3,...25} and T={x,y}$\subset$S then find probability that $x^2-y^2$ is divisible by 7. (x$\neq$y).
>
> 1)$\frac{1}{3}$
>
> 2)$\frac{7}{30}$
>
> 3)$\frac{71}{300}$
>
> 4)$\boxed{\frac{73}{300}}$
>
> Source: All India Open Test for JEE ADVANCED 2022 (conducted by Allen)

My approach to find the number of cases was:

$x-y=7k$, where k$\in${1,2,3,4} or ($\cup$) $x+y=7m$, where m $\in${1,2,3,4,5,6,7} keeping the origin condition of (x,y) $\in$ S. Then, I formed the table of cases by substituting values for y and k. Finally, taking a count of all the cases I could arrive at the desired result.

But, as you might have guessed, this took me a lot of time and the result was error prone too as it was purely based on counting each cases by hand. The exam I am sitting for, expects me to solve each question within 5 minutes (extending to 10 minutes for some actually long ones, but frequency of such questions is small).

So, what should be an optimal approach to this question which would help me get to the answer in lesser time and with more accuracy?

> Edit1 1: This is the official solution provided which seems shorter, but I fail to understand the approach.
>
> [image]

Comment: Well, $x^2\equiv y^2\pmod 7\iff x\equiv \pm y\pmod 7$.  So just count the pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\equiv y \pmod 7$ and $x\equiv -y \pmod 7$ separately.

Comment: That is eventually the same thing I did. I have been provided with an official solution which appears to be shorter but I dont really understand the approach there.

Comment: Should I attach it in the above asked question of mine?

Comment: That method only takes a few lines...hard for me to believe it could be simplified all that much.

Comment: I don't see how to avoid the fact that, if you break the $25$ numbers into equivalence classes $\pmod 7$, the classes don't contain the same number of elements.  If they did, you could greatly speed the work.  And no doubt there are ways to simplify the computation a little, but thinking those through may be no easier than just doing it.

Comment: Yeah, ig you are correct. Made an edit and added the solution as provided.